# How many slaves did the British Empire free between 1700 and 1900?

Tags: british-empire, slavery, atlantic-slave-trade

Parliament's [1833 Slavery Abolition Act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slavery_Abolition_Act_1833) bought, over a six-year time period, the freedom of all slaves in the British Empire

> the Territories in the Possession of the East India Company, or to the Island of Ceylon, or to the Island of Saint Helena." The exceptions were eliminated in 1843.

After an escalation of peaceful protests against the "*apprenticeships*" mandated in the Act, "*Full emancipation for all was legally granted ahead of schedule on 1 August 1838.*"

Additionally, Parliament through the [Indian Slavery Act of 1843](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_Slavery_Act,_1843), the [Upper Canada Act Against Slavery 1793](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Act_Against_Slavery), [Slave Trade Felony Act 1811](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slave_Trade_Felony_Act_1811), and a succession of Slave Trade Acts of [1807](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slave_Trade_Act_1807), [1824](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slave_Trade_Act_1824), [1843](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slave_Trade_Act_1843), and [1873](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slave_Trade_Act_1873) also largely abolished the maritime slave trade across much of the world.

Over the time period from 1700 to 1899, what is the estimated number of slaves freed by action of the British Empire and its subordinate institutions (dominions, possessions, colonies, chartered corporations, military, etc.)?

Comment: Not enough for an answer, but Carter et.al. in [History of the West Indian Peoples, Vol 2](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=nIKkqtPLxeEC) note that "_on 1 August 1838 ... The total number of slaves freed was 831,000; of these 715,000 were in the West Indies_" [p111].

Comment: You could also argue that the English laws on the slave trade at least strongly pushed other countries to abolish slavery. With no slave trade, slavery in Brazil or USA was much less likely to continue.

Comment: @Luiz: Very true - but I am looking for the number of slaves actually freed by direct action, not indirect action, of the British Empire and its subordinate institutions.

Comment: Having the navy interdicting slave ships or bombing slave outposts in Africa is quite 'direct' action. But more to your point: a professor at Sorbonne (Luiz Felipe de Alencastro) some 10y ago published a book with detailed statistics on Portuguese/Brazilian black slavery. It is quite possible that some other works of his have also some statistics about other places or about the English work in the Atlantic in XIX c.